# Download file as word document in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to download an empty word document via `shiny` app?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Create `empty.docx` yourself (either programmatically with pandoc/knitr, or with Word or similar), include it with your package, and return it. However, you say "word document" but your example shows CSV. Which is it?

Comment: .doc but I left the csv example

Comment: can your `content` section instead do `file.copy("path/to/premade/empty.doc", file)`?

Comment: content=function(file.copy("path/to/premade/empty.doc", file)) ?

Comment: No. `content = function(file) file.copy("path/to/premade/empty.doc", file)`

Comment: doesnt seem to work. how can I create the doc inside the shiny app first and then download it via downlaodhandler or actionButton?

Comment: firmo23, that should work if the file **path/to/premade/empty.doc** exists. Why do you want to create the empty word file in Shiny?

Comment: Normally I will create a text in the shiny app and save it as a doc

Comment: does it download an empty doc to you?